# clashing packages

Tags: xetex, packages, option-clash

What shall I do in general if some 2 packages clashes (say in `XeTeX`), but I need them both.
Say I can see the error like this:

```
 !LaTeX Error: Command `\ring' already defined.
```

So how do I comment out the clashing definition ?

Comment: put `\let\ring\undefined` before the second package load (if you do not need the first definition)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Works fine, thank you. What if there are dozens of `already defined`, each one needs its separate `\let\undefined` ?

Comment: in general yes, although in most cases other ways are possible, eg swapping package load order, or one of the packages having an option to skip some sections and avoid the clash or ....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554188/empty-box-instead-of-hieroglyphic-numeral-and-mathabx) Q. ?